# Stripe Checkout Modal : Prefill billing address

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

Is there a way to prefill the billing address form in the Stripe Checkout Form?

I have a form where a customer needs to fill in their address, so I would like to automatically fill the billing address in the Stripe form. However, I am asked by my client to provide the option for their visitors to change the billing address, for instance when they use their personal credit card for a payment they make as a business.

I tried to use the opened() function, but that doesn't seem to affect the Checkout box. Other than that, I don't have an idea what to do..

Comment: Agree - Stripe Checkout is actually very limited right now (Oct 2014), which given it's almost two years old is very surprising. Why can't I provide a customer ID and have everything pre-filled? Why can't we pre-fill *any* data (other than email) for customers new to your stripe checkout? Whilst stripe.js allows for endless customisation, I'm surprised that wasn't translated into their plug and play product. I hope success doesn't hold back such an awesome product / idea.

Comment: I also would love this - hence how I stumbled upon this question! I'm writing a new CRM for my business and each customer has an address book, separate from Stripe. They are primarily for invoices but it would be so nice to be able to just pull their primary address right into Checkout as 9 times out of 10, that's their card billing address too!

Comment: it's 2021 now, any updates on this? It's a bit annoying they have to re-enter their address every time

Answer (score 10):

I e-mailed the Stripe support and got the following reply :

> Unfortunately it's not currently possible to pre-fill Checkout with
>   any details beyond the customer's email﻿. I'll make note of the
>   request and pass it along to our team for consideration(...).

Comment: Did u get any alternative solution ? @Aurelin.

Comment: No, unfortunately I couldn't find a solution other than just having them filling out the billing address.. :/

Answer (score 3):

20 August 2018 update/reply from Stripe:

TLDR: Nope, only email

> I have taken a look into this for you and unfortunately, only the
>   email address can be pre-filled in the Checkout. If you already have
>   the customer’s email address, you can use it to pre-fill the email
>   field in Checkout. The default email address can be pre-filled with
>   `data-email`:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/gkjqcrLp/
>
> The only other way to pre-fill data is actually on the customer's side
>   of things with the Remember Me feature. Customers can enable the
>   “Remember Me” feature when they complete a payment on websites that
>   use Stripe Checkout. If this option is selected and a phone number is
>   entered, a confirmation code is sent via SMS to that mobile device.
>   Because the information would be saved with Stripe, this feature would
>   allow you to make future payments quickly using this mobile
>   verification process.
>
> I appreciate this isn't the answer you were looking for, but I hope
>   that I have been able to shed some light on this, and have given you
>   some information that might be useful going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe told me also on 15 Oct 2015 that only the email can be pre-filled.

However they say we can update the Card with the billing address on the server and get an address verification. They referenced this page (but example code is for an older API version): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27176532

In "test" mode I found it possible to create a Card from a Token and then perform a card update operation with address details added to get an address verification performed. However a Customer object needs to exist first. I could not get a combined card-create-with-address-verification in one step to work though.

```
4000 0000 0000 0028 - simulate address line1 fail
4000 0000 0000 0036 - simulate zip check fail
```

Card update response included these additional properties:

```
{
     ...
     "address_zip_check": "pass",  // or "fail" etc
     "address_line1_check": "pass",
     ...
}
```

Comment: I am guessing your best bet would, in this case, be to first send an ajax request (for instance) to a script that creates the customer, and then use the response to make a second request for the verification.

But that still wouldn't prefill the address, right..?

Comment: No it wouldn't unfortunately. Would you be doing an AVS check?